# How to convert to JSON in a Keyed Format from a CSV file?

Tags: python, json, csv, key

Currently, I'm creating to `JSON` with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("output.csv", sep = ",", header = 0, index_col = False, encoding='utf-8-sig'))
json_file = my_csv.to_json( orient = "records",  date_format = "epoch",   double_precision = 10, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)
file = open("newJsonfile.json", "w") 
file.write(json_file) 
file.close()
```

And the Output is like this:

```
{
    "title": "Sample Title 1 here",
    "description": "Sample description 1 here"
},
    {
    "title": "Sample Title 2 here",
    "description": "Sample description 2 here"
},
```

But, this website : https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm has an option of Keyed `JSON`, after parsing which this output is received:

```
{
   "1": {              
           "title": "Sample Title 1 here",
           "description": "
        },
   "2": {
           "title": "Sample Title 2 here",
           "description": "Sample description 2 here"   
 }
```

How to Achieve this using `Python`, since its not feasible to open this website everytime and do the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I load data in your question:

```py
data = [{
    "title": "Sample Title 1 here",
    "description": "Sample description 1 here"
},
    {
    "title": "Sample Title 2 here",
    "description": "Sample description 2 here"
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

```
                 title                description
0  Sample Title 1 here  Sample description 1 here
1  Sample Title 2 here  Sample description 2 here
```

then , `df.to_json()` with `orient='index'` is ok

```py
json_file = df.to_json(orient='index',indent=4)
print(json_file)
```

```
{
    "0":{
        "title":"Sample Title 1 here",
        "description":"Sample description 1 here"
    },
    "1":{
        "title":"Sample Title 2 here",
        "description":"Sample description 2 here"
    }
}
```

if you want start index from 1 not 0,
you can reindex before `df.to_json()`

```
df.index = range(1,df.shape[0]+1)
json_file = df.to_json(orient='index',indent=4)
print(json_file)
```

```
{
    "1":{
        "title":"Sample Title 1 here",
        "description":"Sample description 1 here"
    },
    "2":{
        "title":"Sample Title 2 here",
        "description":"Sample description 2 here"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keyed = {}
for idx,x in enumerate(a):
    keyed[str(idx)]=x
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.